# Closed ideals in $\mathbb B(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $\mathbb{H}$ be a non-separable Hilbert space.

If $\alpha$ is an countably many infinite cardinal number, let $I_{\alpha}=\{A\in \mathbb{B(H)}\:dim~ cl(ran A)\le \alpha\}.$

Show that $I_{\alpha}$ is a closed ideal in $\mathbb{B(H)}$.

I know that $I_\alpha$ is linear submanifold and is invariant under left and right multiplication. But how to prove that $I_\alpha$ is closed?

Comment: What dimension do you have in mind? And isn't this $\alpha$ just $\aleph_0$?

Comment: @tomasz  yes, $\alpha$ is $\aleph_0$

Answer (score 0):

For any $x\in\mathbb H $ we have $Ax=\lim A_nx$, with $A_nx\in\text {ran }\,A_j $. Because a Hilbert space is metric, we can do this with sequences. Thus
$$
\text {ran}\,A\subset \text {cl}\left (\bigcup_n\text {ran}A_j\right).
$$

Comment: How to show the dimension of right hand side is $\aleph_0$ ?

Comment: Its spanned by a countable union of subspaces each of dimension less than  $\alpha $.

Comment: I know you mean that  $ran A  \subset \overline {span}$ cl$\big(\cup_{n} ran A_j\big) $. I  still can not follow you to think out that the dimension of $\overline {span}$ cl$\big(\cup_{n} ran A_j\big) $ is less that $\alpha$